# xeus-cling install fails in Anaconda

Tags: gcc, anaconda, conda, xeus-cling

I have created a new virtual instance of Ubuntu 18.10

On this fresh installation, I then installed Anaconda as per the installation instructions (using curl, which I also installed).

The next thing I did (quite literally) after verifying conda was correctly installed was to install xeus-cling via

conda install xeus-cling -c QuantStack -c conda-forge

After downloading all the packages, the install fails with this error:

> Executing transaction: failed ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An
>   error occurred while installing package 'QuantStack::gcc-7-7.2.0-2'.
>   LinkError: post-link script failed for package
>   QuantStack::gcc-7-7.2.0-2 running your command again with `-v` will
>   provide additional information location of failed script:
>   /home/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/.gcc-7-post-link.sh
>   ==> script messages <==
>
> Attempting to roll back.
>
> Rolling back transaction: done
>
> LinkError: post-link script failed for package
>   QuantStack::gcc-7-7.2.0-2 running your command again with `-v` will
>   provide additional information location of failed script:
>   /home/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/.gcc-7-post-link.sh
>   ==> script messages <==

I have repeated this several times, and the error is always the same. Any idea how to resolve the problem? It looks like an issue with the version of gcc, but I'm not sure how to resolve/fix it.

Other conda packages (i.e. SciJava) install without problems (tested in other instances of this process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into the same issue and resolved it by running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

I ran into it on the anaconda3 docker image - so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I will try this for sure and report back.

Comment: (I also ran 'sudo apt-get upgrade' on my Ubuntu server before installing build-essential just to be on the safe side with updates)